# RealmChangeListener onChange() never fires

Tags: android, realm

Realm Version: `2.1.1`

I have a fragment and in it's `onCreate()` I register a `RealmChangeListener`. However, when my object is updated, the `RealmChangeListener`'s `onChange()` never fires.

Actually, that is a lie, for some strange reason if I clean install my app it will work a few times before not working at all for all until I uninstall/reinstall the app again.

I know for a fact my `Realm` operations are writing to `Realm` because if I restart my app, the UI definitely displays those new changes. No idea why maybe the listeners would unregister?

Feeling a little confused here, I hope I am not doing something wrong:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private Realm mRealm;
    private RealmChangeListener mRealmChangeListener;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

            // Get user from Realm
            RealmQuery<User> query = mRealm.where(User.class);
            User user = query.findFirst();

            updateUI(user);

            mRealmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener<User>() {
                @Override
                public void onChange(User user) {
                    updateUI(user);
                }
            };

            user.addChangeListener(mRealmChangeListener);

        }

        // Todo:
        // Unregister listeners + realm in OnDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem could be that you don't actually retain a strong reference to your `User` object.

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private Realm mRealm;
    private RealmChangeListener mRealmChangeListener;
    private User user;

...

            // Get user from Realm
            RealmQuery<User> query = mRealm.where(User.class);
            user = query.findFirst();
```

Also, you're in a fragment, so you should consider moving the `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()` to `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()` (unless this is a retained fragment, in which case go ahead).

If the problem persists, report back here.

Comment: Awesome! It was that I did not have a strong reference to my User object like you said. Works great now :) Thanks.